# wpf access lisbox selected item if it isn't string

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, observablecollection

I have a listbox which displays `Name` property from an array of `Movie` objects

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                              <DataTemplate >                                      
                                     <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Name}"/> 
                              </DataTemplate>
                          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl>
                 </ListBox>
```

How can I access the text of the textBlock that's inside the ListBox in Code?
I must use the value of the Name property in my code

Answer (score 1):

The selected item reported by the listbox exposes you the object that owns the Name property bound in the TextBlock. At this point the game is over.

Comment: i tried   

        `Dim tempTB As TextBlock = CType(listBox1.SelectedItem, TextBlock)` but it won't cast from ItemsControl to TextBlock

Comment: No. What is the object that exposes the "Name" property that you used on the Text binding? The SelectedItem property gives that object. Forget the TextBlock!

Comment: i tried `Dim tempMv As Movie = CType(listBox1.SelectedItem, Movie)`
but it gave the same error.  

i have `Me.listBox1.DataContext = Me.movieArray` with 
`movieArray = new ObservableCollection(of Movie)`

Comment: If you set the DataContext via code, then cut the {Binding} on the ItemsSource in the xaml: don't use both. First: do you see the names on the list? Second: in the SelectionChanged event handler, what is the object exposed by the SelectedItem?

Comment: it doesn't show anything if i remove the Itemssource binding,  
the object type is System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl

Comment: You should paste a bit some code, because there's something contradictory in your info. Just restore the ItemsSource binding, then check the collection content, the effective DataContext of the listbox. If that's correct, you should see something on the list. When the list shows some name, the cast must work.

Comment: @MarioVernari let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2102/discussion-between-sitsonredchair-and-mario-vernari)

Comment: the XAML is the same as i posted in the question, the handler for selection changed looks like this:  

`Private Sub listBox1_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) 

NextButton.IsEnabled = True 
'Dim tempMovie1 As Movie = CType(listBox1.SelectedItem, Movie) 

label1.Content = listBox1.SelectedItem.GetType()`
it shows names properly with the XMAL from the question, but i cant select items

Comment: Made it work! I used `ListBox.ItemTemplate` instead of `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. This was just wierd WPF behavior.

Comment: Huh!...shame on me!...I didn't realize that the xaml had no sense!...I am sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When you do the above every textblock inside the itemscontrol has a name textblock1 that too with a scope limited to each item container.

If you want each of those textblocks individually, I usually do something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"/>
```

And in the code register those textboxes in whatever way you wish. A list probably,

```
List<TextBlock> TextBlockList = new List<TextBlock>();

private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlockList.Add((TextBlock)sender);           
        }
```

And for example, access the stuff as:

```
String FirstItem = TextBlockList.ElementAt(0).Text;
```